# rsync - unexpected remote arg

Tags: rsync

I am trying to rsync a folder from remote to local but get an error below. I googled but can't find a solution that works.

```
kong@kong-P15SM:/media/kong/Elements$ rsync -r -i /home/kong/.ssh/id_rsantu --exclude=dataset/ e130167@35.123.456.78:~/sgan-original/ ./sgan-original/
Unexpected remote arg: e130167@35.123.456.78:~/sgan-original/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Comment: solution doesnt work

Comment: Hello. Comments are not for you to add info. Use edit and add to the question. Comments for people who want to help to ask you for info.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
rsync -r -e "ssh -i /home/kong/.ssh/id_rsantu" --exclude=dataset/ e130167@35.123.456.78:~/sgan-original/ ./sgan-original/
```

as posted here https://superuser.com/questions/1379574/rsync-unexpected-remote-arg/1379576#1379576

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -auHxvz /* --exclude=/.ssh/* --exclude=/etc/fstab --exclude=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/boot/* --exclude=/root/* root@159.xxx.xx.xxx:/ --progress
```

this command worked fine with me.